# jQuery mobile: Page transition effects are barely noticeable

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I've tried to look at to jQuery mobile demos on desktop FireFox, then on Android Emulator, then on HTC Hero (dolphin browser) - and page transition effects are barely noticeable, if not at all. What can be the cause of this? Only on Chrome I could see some results. Is this feature "not mature" and while developing jQuery mobile apps I shouldn't rely on it too much?

This also brings a question of **safe development**, it would be valuable to know, which features of jQuery mobile shouldn't be too much relied upon. This is even a more important question, I'd appreciate your considerations!

P.S.I've browsed demos from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html.

Comment: What transition are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been in the business for a long time, and spent my first ten years writing code for a platform that was rock solid where change was rare and new features were very carefully and painstakingly tested before being released into the wild.  *By that standard*, there is nothing today that should be relied on, especially in the browser sphere where change is incessant and your code that worked in January might no longer work in June. The browser "platform" is a moving target, a chimera.

P.S. I'll back this opinion up with a case in point.  I completely redesigned a site to use jQuery-UI tabs and it worked flawlessly across all browsers including iPad Safari. Then Apple did something and the pages no longer render properly on the iPad1 but do render properly on the iPad2.